# Store the value of Checked checkbox in a variable using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have created group of checkbox using ng-repeat using the below days object value.

```
$scope.config = { days: [
             {name:'Monday'},
             {name:'Tuesday'},
             {name:'Wednesday'},
             {name:'Thursday'},
             {name:'Friday'},
             {name:'Saturday'},
             {name:'Sunday'},
        ]}
});
```

My checkbox using ng-repeat is like that.

```
<ul class="list-inline">
<li ng-repeat="day in config.days">
    <div class="checkbox">   
        <label class="xsm-label">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="day.selected" value="{{day.name}}" id="cs_select_{{day.name}}" name="selected_days" />&nbsp;{{day.name}}
        </label>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

I tried much but no luck, kindly help me how to store value of checked checkbox value in a variable.

Thank you.

Comment: what's working? what does it display? maybe it's because the ".selected" property does not exist on your days...

Answer (score 3):

You may need to use `ng-change` directive to execute the on change method of the check box, Inside a function you can store checked values

```
$scope.selected = function(day, index) {
    day.selected ? $scope._selected.push(day.name) : $scope._selected.splice(index, 1)
}
```

Your html should look like following:

```
 <li ng-repeat="day in config.days">
    <div class="checkbox">
        <label class="xsm-label">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="day.selected" value="{{day.name}}" id="cs_select_{{day.name}}" 
          name="selected_days" ng-change="selected(day, $index)"/>&nbsp;{{day.name}}
                                          ^^^^^^^^^This ^^^^^^^^^
        </label>
    </div>
 </li>
```

[Working Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/sqSDLe89GB4t0v0Bndg0?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ng-change`, whenever a checkbox is checked, update the variable with new value.

Below line of code will keep the last selected checkbox, you could replace it with an empty string if necessary.

```
$scope.selectedDay= day.selected ? day.name : $scope.selectedDay;
```

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []).controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) { 

  $scope.config = { days: [
             {name:'Monday'},
             {name:'Tuesday'},
             {name:'Wednesday'},
             {name:'Thursday'},
             {name:'Friday'},
             {name:'Saturday'},
             {name:'Sunday'},
        ]};
        
        
  $scope.storeValue = function(day) {
    $scope.selectedDay= day.selected ? day.name : $scope.selectedDay;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<ul class="list-inline">
<li ng-repeat="day in config.days">
    <div class="checkbox">   
        <label class="xsm-label">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="day.selected" value="{{day.name}}" id="cs_select_{{day.name}}" name="selected_days" ng-change="storeValue(day)" />&nbsp;{{day.name}}
        </label>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>

{{selectedDay}}
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's OK. You can get selected value by loop on `config.days` array and get the item that `selected`  is `true`.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('main', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.config = { days: [
             {name:'Monday'},
             {name:'Tuesday'},
             {name:'Wednesday'},
             {name:'Thursday'},
             {name:'Friday'},
             {name:'Saturday'},
             {name:'Sunday'},
        ]};
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

  <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main">
<ul class="list-inline">
<li ng-repeat="day in config.days">
    <div class="checkbox">   
        <label class="xsm-label">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="day.selected" value="{{day.name}}" id="cs_select_{{day.name}}" name="selected_days" />&nbsp;{{day.name}}
        </label>
    </div>
</li>
</ul>  
<pre>{{config.days | json}}</pre>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include in your input directive `ng-change="onChange(day)"`:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="day.selected" id="cs_select_{{day.name}}" name="selected_days" 
            ng-change="onChange(day)"/>&nbsp;{{day.name}}
```

Then, in your controller, define a function as:

```
        $scope.onChange = function(day) {

            $scope.lastSelectedDayValue = day.selected ? day.name : '';

            $scope.allSelectedDays = $scope.config.days.filter(function(day){ 
                                                        return day.selected 
                                                    }).map(function(day){
                                                        return day.name 
                                                    });
        }
```

You will have in `$scope.lastSelectedDayValue` the last day where you clicked, and in `$scope.allSelectedDays` an array with all days that are selected in the current moment.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.config = { days: [
             {name:'Monday'},
             {name:'Tuesday'},
             {name:'Wednesday'},
             {name:'Thursday'},
             {name:'Friday'},
             {name:'Saturday'},
             {name:'Sunday'},
        ]};
        
    var arr = [];    
    $scope.getSelected = function(selectedDay) {
      if(arr.indexOf(selectedDay) == -1) {
        arr.push(selectedDay);
      }
      console.log(arr);
    }
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <ul class="list-inline">
<li ng-repeat="day in config.days">
    <div class="checkbox">   
        <label class="xsm-label">
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedDay" value="{{day.name}}" id="cs_select_{{day.name}}" name="selected_days" ng-change="getSelected(day.name)"/>&nbsp;{{day.name}}
        </label>
    </div>
</li>
</ul> 
</div>
```